# 'zoom out' on linux/VNC viewer

Tags: linux, vnc

Until recently I have used vnc viewer to scale my desktop down.  I would start my server with a huge desktop size, then set my viewer to fit to scale.  This effectively shrunk not just the text but all gui settings as well, and in so doing giving me an effectively larger screen real estate at the expense of smaller icon/text.

Now I'm being forced to switch to a far more limited vncviewer tool, I can't even download a better free viewer, due to company rules.  I no longer have a zoom-to-fit option on my viewer.  Suddently all my gui tools feel huge and cumbersom and I miss all my effective screen realestate I've lost.  Is there a way to get a similar effect using only linux and VNC server options?  I want to scale down not just text, but all gui icons and spacing as well.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal XVNC server does not have a scale or shrink option, afaict. x11vnc has that, but since that is bound to the resolution of the physical screen it makes a lot of sense in that context.

A completely virtual screen can be set to whatever resolution you like, so the developers maybe didn't think such a feature would make much sense.

What you could try to do is to set a lower DPI value for fonts, but that won't scale down icons and stuff. Maybe it will at least help you.

You can't convince your boss to let you use vinagre or something? It should be in the default repositories for most distros.